# Is it acceptable to recommend a framework or library in an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today I answered a question where the OP wanted to create a modal with a custom dim background. I wanted to pass along a good habit of not re-inventing the wheel, so I told him to check out [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

And in the answer ([not sure if I'm allowed to link my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342406/5870134)) I showed the OP how to do what `(sh|h)e` wanted (regex made me lazy). The OP accepted my answer and that is that.

The thing is, I'm not sure if what I've done was the right thing to do.

Did I do the right thing? If not, what should I do the next time this happens?

Comment: "I'm not sure if what I've done was the right thing to do" -- Does your concern have to do with some specific rule, such as the "recommendation" close reason?

Comment: If you explained why using Bootstrap is better than reinventing the wheel in your answer then everything should be fine.

Comment: Regexen should be *lazier*: `s?he`.

Comment: Just use singular they ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to recommend a framework, but it has to be done **in the context of solving a problem**.  Merely linking them to the framework and telling them, "Have fun!" isn't the best approach, since it would appear to be a lazy answer at *best*, and link-only at *worst*.

For example, suppose this were your answer:

> You should check out [BlazFramework](http://www.example.com).  It does all of the things you're looking to do and more.

That's link-only and fairly lazy.

If this were your answer:

> It looks like [BlazFramework's MediaDisplayer](http://www.example.com) can give you what you're looking for.  You would need to specify the foo and the bar, but once you do, you can call `baz()`.
>
> This is better because it saves you having to address issues with certain platforms not having the right codecs to run WebM, and it saves you the trouble of having to build the fallbacks - you can also specify the blaz to describe the fallback behavior.
>
> Here's an abbreviated example of what you'd need to do:
>
> ```
> // Moderate length code snippet
> ```

It'd be *better*.

Comment: For the ones that hasn't noticed, BlazFramework is another name of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, appreciate it.

Comment: @Braiam [-1 not enough BlazFramework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/292385)

Comment: Except, of course, if the question is a javascript question that does not contain a framework tag. [*"Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag."*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). It is fairly common for people to recommend using large bloated frameworks to solve simple javascript problems.

Comment: @TinyGiant Even in that context I think it would be fine to answer something along the lines of *"Here's how you solve it using plain javascript <commented code> but I would really recommend using a framework like BlazFramework for this as it drives a lot of people nuts when you do and it's fun to watch them rage"*

Comment: @ivarni I would still down vote such an answer.