# How could I have better shared an open-source library that I wrote?

Tags: discussion, scope, spam

If I understand it correctly, the voting system should help reduce as much as possible the influence of the subjective opinions, leaving a mean estimate of the question/answer's quality made by the majority of the users. The problem I am addressing is that for this to work, the post should reach enough users and let them express their opinion about it with up/downvoting. However the post might be flagged as off-topic and closed or deleted long before that happens. In other words that, what a couple of people (even with a high rep.) find inappropriate, might be actually beneficial for hundreds or thousands other users.

In that order of thoughts, I have a hard time to exaplain to myself why [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400254/how-to-draw-a-qr-code-with-qt-in-native-c-c) (which I find really helpful indeed) is well received, though [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431021/non-native-gui-elements-for-windows-desktop-applications-using-qt5-c-without-q) is considered as off-topic or even spam for:

> asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource

Technically speaking, both questions ask for an off-site resource, though there is a difference in their reception. May we speak about double standards here or there is something I am missing?

I am not asking this because I don't want my question to be closed. Actually, I've deleted it myself and I prefer that it remains so. After all my goal was to give something back to the community which helped me along the way and to feel bad about it is the last thing I would like. The reason why I am asking this is that I would like to know how that should be in general.

A screenshot of the deleted post:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the 2nd post please, such that users under 10k rep can see it?

Comment: @TheDude, with pleasure.

Comment: This very post was highlighted on Meta yesterday: [Is it appropriate to create a question to promote software?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362476)

Comment: Your question is marked as spam. As far as I can see, you just created the question to promote a library you wrote with a self-answer.

Comment: What is the difference with the first post apart from being asked/answered by the same person?

Comment: I don't see how the first one is a request for off-site resources, it asks how to generate a QR code. It has some superfluous demands which make it read like a work order ("nimble", that's a new one for me), but those can be edited out and it's still a valid question.

Comment: @Gimby, Without seeking any confrontation and with all my respect: Does it mean that if I change the "Is there something..." to "How I could do that" it makes the question legal? Again, I am asking to make the things clear to myself, not to argue.

Comment: Related: [How to ask and self answer a correct high quality QA pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165)

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I will read that. Thanks for the resource!

Comment: @scopchanov It could be that simple, but it is not guaranteed. It depends on the nature of the question as a whole. Including the reason for posting it.

Comment: I assume that you meant well, and simply wanted to offer your library to help other users. Unfortunately, that Q&A is still [overt self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), which is against the site's rules. You *are* allowed, however, to mention your own work in your profile page. That includes links to GitHub libraries.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, the accepted answer in the post I am comparing with is also linking to own third party library. That is why I thought it might be a good idea to share it like this, using the Q&A style of SO.

Answer (score 7):

> Technically speaking, both questions ask for an off-site resource, though there is a difference in their reception. May we speak about double standards here or there is something I am missing?

Yes, there is something you are missing. The older post has an answer by the OP that gives step-by-step instructions on how to use a 3rd-party library to solve a specific problem. Your answer just links to your Github repo.

Comment: I am asking about the question, not the answer.

Comment: @scopchanov Your question was only posted so you could post the answer. I'm not going to try and separate the two.

Comment: Closely related:  [Is it acceptable to recommend a framework or library in an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342405) | [Is it acceptable to promote my own library as part of a real answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298734)

Comment: @JoshCaswell, again, thanks for the resources! From what I've saw on the go, the answer to those questions is _yes_, though I need to put more effort in making the problem-solution more specific and thorough. Did I get that right?

Comment: That would be my suggestion, @scopchanov. It was also suggested [on the Meta question yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362476/is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-question-to-promote-software#comment551749_362476).

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I see and I will do that. I have one more question though about something mentioned in your last link - "disclose their affiliation". What does that mean?

Comment: You already covered that when you said "The FlatGUI library **I have created**", @scopchanov.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I see. Thank you for your time, information and explanations! That was helpful to me in order to learn further rules. As for my post, as I've said, I prefer to leave it deleted because of the mentioned reasons.